# How can i use the uploaded image as featured image in wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just upload 250x250 resolution images for all of my post. When i set one of the image as featured its getting cropped into 250x198.

I just want to use the uploaded image itself without any modification. I have tried Thumbnail Re-builder plugin,even it doesn't help me out.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the post thumbnail dimensions:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

In your theme's functions.php file, add this line:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250, true )`;

You will need to rebuild your thumbnails after doing this.  Ajax thumbnail rebuild is a great plugin for that.

See the codex link for more explanation.

Comment: @John. i'm new to wordpress,under which function i need to add this one?

Comment: It just needs to sit on a line by itself in functions.php